# Mongo Aggregation Query - Filter Condition where string contains value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo query filtering input from "notes". Notes is an array of objects containing the fields user, date, and comment.  This is the schema of the notes array:

```
notes: [ { comment: { type: String }, user: { type: String }, date: { type: Date }}]
```

I'm successfully using $addFields with $filter to remove comments from an admin user. I'm also wanting to ensure comments contain a string "m]". It seems like I'm unable to use a regular expression. Anyone know a way to approach this?

```
{
    $addFields: {
        notes: {
            $filter: {
                input: '$notes',
                as: 'note',
                cond: { $and: [ 
                      { $ne: ['$$note.user', 'admin'] },
                      { $eq: ['$$note.comment', /.*m].*/i ] }, 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

I'm currently running Mongo v4.0.28 so $regexMatch does not appear to be an option.

I have created a Mongo Playground to better illustrate the issue:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/uyOVhIXSFQf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$indexOfBytes`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/) instead of `$eq`:

```
[{
  $addFields: {
    notes: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$notes",
        as: "note",
        cond: {
          $and: [{
              $ne: [
                "$$note.user",
                "admin"
              ]
            },
            {
              $ne: [
                -1,
                {
                  $indexOfBytes: [
                    "$$note.comment",
                    "m"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

Updated [MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tUDkYeU9nRa).

Comment: I saw the documentation for $regexMatch. However, I don't think it's available in Mongo v4.0.28. Is there any other option ?

Comment: @AndrewTaylor missed the version! Can you try `$indexOfBytes` as in the updated answer?